# Calling specific method after another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm retrieving data from my parse database and looping it into an NSMutableArray. This is in my getHomes method, which is being called in viewDidLoad. The NSMutableArray contain various UIImages, which CGSize' i'm looping through. This method is called getCellHeights. I want to call this method right after the getHomes method, but stacking them like this in viewdidLoad does not do the trick. The getCellHeights method is not running since there is no objects in the NSMutableArray, cause its not completed with the retrieving of data.

How can i make sure that the getCellHeights is not running before the getHomes method is completed?

## getCellHeights

```
-(void)getcellHeights {
    for (int i = 0; i < homesDic.count; i++) {


        UIImage *image = [[homesDic objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"];
        CGFloat divider = image.size.width/145;

        CGFloat wantedWidth = 145;
        CGFloat wantedHeight = image.size.height/divider;

        NSLog(@"width: %f height: %f", wantedWidth, wantedHeight);

        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(wantedWidth, wantedHeight);

        [_cellSizes addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:size]];

    }
}
```

## getHomes

```
-(void)getHomes {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Homes"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects1, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            for (PFObject *object in objects1) {




                PFQuery *userQ = [PFUser query];
                [userQ getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[object objectForKey:@"userId"] block:^(PFObject *userName, NSError *error) {

                    NSLog(@"%@", userName);

                    [[userName objectForKey:@"file"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                        UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



                        PFQuery *homeQ = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"homeImages"];
                        [homeQ whereKey:@"homeId" equalTo:object.objectId];
                        [homeQ whereKey:@"number" equalTo:@(0)];
                        [homeQ findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                PFQuery *cityQ = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"City"];
                                id zip = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [[object objectForKey:@"zip"] intValue]];


                                [cityQ whereKey:@"fra" greaterThanOrEqualTo:zip];
                                [cityQ whereKey:@"fra" lessThanOrEqualTo:zip];
                                [cityQ findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *cObject, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {

                                        PFObject *cityObject = [cObject lastObject];






                                        PFObject *image = [objects lastObject];

                                        [[image objectForKey:@"Image"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];




                                                NSMutableDictionary *flagDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                                                [flagDict setObject:[object objectForKey:@"title"] forKey:@"title"];
                                                [flagDict setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
                                                [flagDict setObject:[cityObject objectForKey:@"navn"] forKey:@"city"];
                                                [flagDict setObject:[userName objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
                                                [flagDict setObject:profileImage forKey:@"profileImage"];


                                                [homesDic addObject:flagDict];


                                                [self.collectionView reloadData];


                                            } else {
                                                // Log details of the failure
                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                                            }







                                        }];


                                    }

                                }];

                            }

                        }];

                    }];



                }];




            }





        } else {
        // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }


    }];

}
```

Comment: What is `getHomes` doing that's asynchronous?

Comment: getHomes gets data from some service ? is there a completion handler where you can add a callback and call getCellHeights ?

Comment: Showing code of the getHomes will be nice

Comment: i've added both methods now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blocks that you're passing to the Parse framework query methods are completion/callback Blocks; when the fetch has completed, they are run. Do whatever you need to do after the fetch -- including calling `cellHeights` -- in the appropriate completion Block.

Comment: well i tried to put the getCellHeights in the block, but since the main query in the getHomes is a loop, it will call the getHomes several times. How would u recommend me to implement the getCellHeight in getHomes?

Comment: Put the call outside the loop.

Comment: Then it the homeDic.count return 0 since it is being executed before the objects has been added to homeDic